# Change Wordpress menu according to template

Tags: wordpress, templates, menu

I would like to have different Wordpress menus for different page templates. For example, I would like all the pages with the "Full Width" template to use the "Main" menu but all the "Services" template pages to use the "Secondary" menu. Can I create an if statement to accomplish this? Here is the code my header template has right now.

```
<nav id="navigation" class="clearfix">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'main_menu',
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'menu_class' => 'sf-menu',
        'fallback_cb' => false,
        'walker' => new wpex_menu_walker()
    )); ?>
</nav><!-- /navigation -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always conditions over here.. try this bro this may help in header.php

```
if ( is_page_template( 'fullwidth.php' ) ) {
  //your nav stuffs here wp_nav_menu
} elseif( is_page_template( 'services.php' ) ) {
// your services menu using wp_nav_menu
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks dude.